# Is it possible to trim a workout from an Apple Watch?

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app, activity.app

Sometimes I forget to stop my workout and end up with a long running "workout" in the health app. Some apps (i.e. Strava) have a method for trimming down a workout if you remember what time the workout ended.

Is there a way to do that from the Workout watch app? Or in the Health.app on the iPhone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of watchOS 4.0 and iOS 11.0 there is no way to adjust the length of a workout with Apple Watch or iPhone.

I experienced the same issue in the past and the only known way to do this is by

1. creating an encrypted backup with iTunes and to
2. edit the Health.app SQL database's entries
3. Restore the backup to your iPhone.

You should let Apple know that this is a feature you want to see in future releases:

https://www.apple.com/feedback/watch.html

Comment: (I will wait a little while before accepting, just in case someone else has an easier way.)